# How to get place report responses (google api)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, google-maps

I need get place report responses with rails code. please suggest me a the way.

Ref link:http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceReportResponses

Comment: 1st thought, are you using a form helper to ensure the CSRF values are passed?  If that's not the issue, we're gonna need a lot more info here on what's happening, and probably some code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Curl gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/curb) or rest-client gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client)